# How to restore Emacs after testing the bug on clean Emacs?

Tags: evil

I want to submit an evil bug report as described in
https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#bug-reports

> 2. Test the bug in a clean Emacs environment without any additional packages loaded (besides Evil itself). You can easily get such an
>      environment by executing either make emacs (for X) or make terminal
>      (for terminal mode) in Evil's source directory. If your bug is related
>      to some other package, try to load only this package from the clean
>      environment after using M-x package-initialize first.

After testing the bug on clean Emacs as described in step 2, what is the procedure for restoring Emacs to how it was before the test?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil Spacemacs and Ivy on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding something there.  Running `make emacs` or `make terminal` spawns a separate Emacs instance that only loads up Evil from its source directory.  This instance doesn't use your own config and doesn't modify it either.  Once you close it that test environment it is completely gone.

The only way you could achieve what you've described is by deliberately ignoring the instructions, deleting your init files and using that setup for testing.  I recommend against such drastic action as it's rarely needed if ever, a non-destructive way of achieving the same is moving the files to a different location and moving them back afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  Where are the "make emacs" instructions?  Or what directory do I run "make emacs" from?

Comment: To quote from the instructions, "in Evil's source directory".  If you haven't done so already, fetch a copy with `git clone https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil`.

Comment: How to install org-mode on the clean Emacs environment?  After cloning evil and "make emacs", Emacs started and I tried "M-x package-initialize" but it didn't do anything.  There is no InitFile in the evil directory.

Comment: Org is bundled with Emacs, so this isn't needed.  Just open the file and `M-x org-mode`.